# Text doesn't fit in the box. CSS issue

Tags: html, css

```
background:url(images/page_text.png) repeat-y;  
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 949px;
padding: 20px;
line-height: 100%;
```

That was my css. What is wrong? When I write long sentence, it doesn't fit in the page_text.png box (It is funny, but only in IE, it works fine). I think I am missing something.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more context that that. Can you provide the html markup and the css selector?

Comment: `<div id="css_id_name">And long sentence goes here...</div>`

Comment: Can you kindly set up the page in http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can see what you see? Thanks.

Comment: @invalidsyntax: sure, here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dP2m/

Comment: Your question talks about a 'long sentence' but all the answer have you stating 'it's an image' so, we really can't help until you clarify all of this for us.

Comment: @hey: If you need to use an image, make an accurate jsFiddle test case including an image (showing your problem). Use [http://dummyimage.com/](http://dummyimage.com/) to get an image.

Comment: I second @thirtydot . The jsfiddle is using different CSS than the CSS you posted. This makes it very hard for us to provide you with an accurate response.

Comment: @hey Have you given up on getting help for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set word-break... unfortunately, it's not consistent across browsers, so you use the code below to force it on all browsers. It's [explained here](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/02/firefox-ie-word-wrap-word-break-tables.html)

```
white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are talking about a long word and not a long sentence. In that case you can use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: actually I mean long sentence, but I couldn't do that in jsfiddle, because it requires image.

Comment: @hey My answer is based on the jsfiddle you posted. There is no image there so I don´t have clue as to what the problem is apart from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Set [`overflow:hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow) (CSS2) to hide the overflow on browsers that don't support the [`word-wrap:break-word`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap0) (CSS3) to force a word break in the middle of a pathologically long word.

**Edit**: See the test case here, with an image: http://jsfiddle.net/8dP2m/4/

**Edit 2**: And here it is with the image in the background: http://jsfiddle.net/8dP2m/7/

When asking for HTML/CSS help, please provide:

1. Your actual code (you followed up with this in comments, though you should edit your question to include it). A pared-down test case showing the actual problem on JSFiddle is best.
2. What you hoped to see.
3. What you see instead (making it clear how this differs from #2).
4. On what OS/browser/version you are experiencing the trouble.

Comment: doesn't help in my case with image

Comment: @hey I don't know what that means. Provide an accurate test case and clear description if you want accurate answers. Setting `overflow:hidden` will prevent an image from overflowing the boundaries of the container.